# java.lang.NullPointerException when making signed request to AWS Lambda Function URL using AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke an AWS Lambda function with a Function URL from within a Java application.  I've been trying to sign my request using the java aws sdk with no success for longer than I'd like to admit.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  I'm using java aws sdk 2.18.7.  I have the access key and secret key of the user with access to execute the lambda function url.

Here is my code. It is crashing on the last line (150) "Response awsResponse = reb.execute();"

```
Request<Void> request = new DefaultRequest<Void>("lambda");
request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.POST);
request.setEndpoint(URI.create(this.LAMBDA_URL));
request.setContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(postJsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postJsonString.length()));
request.setHeaders(headers);
// Sign AWS Request
AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
signer.setRegionName(MY_REGION);
signer.setServiceName(request.getServiceName());
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
signer.sign(request, awsCreds);
// Execute and get response
ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
AmazonHttpClient client = new AmazonHttpClient(config);
RequestExecutionBuilder reb = client.requestExecutionBuilder();
reb = reb.request(request);
reb = reb.executionContext(new ExecutionContext());
Response<Void> awsResponse = reb.execute();
```

Here is the output in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1879)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1418)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1387)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:702)
    at aws_auth_awssdk2_18_7.Main.aws_sdk_attemp(Main.java:150)
    at aws_auth_awssdk2_18_7.Main.main(Main.java:67)
```

Comment: If you want to invoke a Lambda function from Java, try using the AWS Java V2 software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaClient object. Ref here -- https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/lambda/LambdaClient.html

Comment: You code is using V1 version of the AWS SDK, V1 packages start with com.amazonaws.... V2 uses software.amazon...